Is there any way to define folders for the segmented files of a transcoded video in Google Cloud Transcoder API?
I'm working with video transcoding using the Google Cloud Transcoder API.
Considering that my partial job configuration is this:
{
  "elementaryStreams": [
    {
      "key": "video-stream1",
      "videoStream": {
        "h264": {
          "heightPixels": 144,
          "widthPixels": 256,
          "bitrateBps": 216000,
          "frameRate": 25,
          "pixelFormat": "yuv420p",
          "rateControlMode": "vbr",
          "bFrameCount": 3,
          "profile": "main",
          "enableTwoPass": true,
          "preset": "slow"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "video-stream2",
      "videoStream": {
        "h264": {
          "heightPixels": 240,
          "widthPixels": 428,
          "bitrateBps": 360000,
          "frameRate": 25,
          "pixelFormat": "yuv420p",
          "rateControlMode": "crf",
          "crfLevel": 10,
          "bFrameCount": 3,
          "aqStrength": 1,
          "profile": "main",
          "tune": "film",
          "preset": "medium"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "audio-stream0",
      "audioStream": {
        "codec": "aac",
        "bitrateBps": 96000
      }
    }
  ],
  "muxStreams": [
    {
      "key": "144p-ts",
      "container": "ts",
      "elementaryStreams": [
        "video-stream1",
        "audio-stream0"
      ],
      "segmentSettings": {
        "individualSegments": true
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "240p-ts",
      "container": "ts",
      "elementaryStreams": [
        "video-stream2",
        "audio-stream0"
      ],
      "segmentSettings": {
        "individualSegments": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "manifests": [
    {
      "fileName": "manifest.m3u8",
      "type": "HLS",
      "muxStreams": [
        "144p-ts",
        "240p-ts"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Note: The input and output fields are defined dynamically in my Node.js code.
This way, the video segments are stored in the bucket as shown in the image below:
bucket output folder image
I would like to group the segment files into a specific folder associated with the video resolution.
The expected result would be this:

144p/ (folder where the 144p resolution segments should be)
244p/ (folder where the 240p resolution segments should be)
144p-ts.m3u8
240p-ts.m3u8
manifest.m3u8

I didn't find anything in the documentation that allows me to do this.
